# Which headset are supported by OpenVR

Tags: oculus, openvr

I was wondering, without any additional driver, just with the compiled library.

I searched but didn't find any clear answer

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<del>As far as I know, at this point only the HTC Vive is a real working OpenVR (SteamVR) headset. There might be some other one-of-a-kind hacked prototypes or companies that claim that they will be using OpenVR in their product, but nothing that someone can just buy.</del>

**Update**: can confirm that Oculus Rift DK2 and CV1 are supported. They work fairly well, sometimes with gamma issues. SteamVR runs Oculus Home in the background and does composite the chaperone bounds like it would with Vive.

Comment: I found this: http://www.roadtovr.com/making-valves-openvr-truly-inclusive-for-vr-headsets/
"OpenVR is tied to SteamVR, which I soon found out had poor support for the Oculus Rift out of the box. Even the ‘hello world’ VR demo ran very poorly when I strapped on my Rift"

Comment: SteamVR did not even detect my Rift DK2, maybe with the production version (still waiting for the package)?

Answer (score 0):

Like the other folks have stated, it really only supports the HTC Vive.

If you're looking for a generic system, you're out of luck, unless you use Unity, Unreal, or the assorted VR vendors begin writing software to conform to the Microsoft Holographic APIs.

Comment: Isn't the MS Holographic API supposed to be only for AR uses? Also, I see no effort from Microsoft or other vendors to support anything more than Hololens.

Comment: The Holographic API is generic -- it would support VR just fine.  It's true that no one but MS has a device that uses it, but that could change very easily, if vendors would step away from trying to own the ecosystem with their own APIs.

Comment: The same could be said either way - maybe MS should step down and target OpenVR, joining the consortium and extending with the AR part? Giving away control like that won't happen without any other incentives, and currently there are none from MS. As a developer or hardware maker, OpenVR gives you these - it's aggressively pushed to a big target audiance by Steam plus it works fairly well and hardware is available in stores.